# Store data from table into associative array

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, row

I am trying to store data into an associative array from table.
Here is my html table code:

```
<table class="table" border="1" id="eidtPersonalInfoTbl">         
    <tr>    
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone">Name</td>    
        <td class="span5"> Name of Doctor </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr> 
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone">Address</td>
        <td class="span5"> Address of doctor </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone">Area</td>
        <td class="span5"> Area</td>
    <tr>
 <table>
```

and I am trying to access table values by this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.editPersonalInfo', function() {
        modal();
        alert(obj['Name']);
        alert(obj['Address']);
        alert(obj['Area']);
    });

    function modal() {
        var table = $("#eidtPersonalInfoTbl");
        var trs = table.find('tr');
        var obj = {};
        $(trs).each(function(index, row) {
            var field = $(row).find('td').eq(0).text();
            var value = $(row).find('td').eq(1).text();
            obj[field] = [value];
        });
    }
</script>
```

but it is not working. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the JavaScript code located? Wrapping it around .ready would probably be a step forward.

Comment: There are no elements with the class `editPersonalInfo` in that code ?

Comment: @adeneo `editPersonInfo` is a button's element class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have any `editPersonalInfo` class in HTML markup. Use `#eidtPersonalInfoTbl` instead.

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#eidtPersonalInfoTbl', function () {
    var obj = modal(); //store object in a variable
    alert(obj['Name']);
    alert(obj['Address']);
    alert(obj['Area']);
});

function modal() {
    var table = $("#eidtPersonalInfoTbl");
    var trs = table.find('tr');
    var obj = {};
    $(trs).each(function (index, row) {
        var field = $(row).find('td').eq(0).text();
        var value = $(row).find('td').eq(1).text();
        obj[field] = [value];
    });
    return obj; //return object
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UFwwz/1)